# How to put a spinner inside of the button in React?

Tags: reactjs

[See current Spinner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMPZD.png)

Hello,
I like to put the current spinner inside the Login button, but it is located outside of the button. Any help? Thank you in advance!

Here are my codes.

[Login.js] try to load  when user clicks the Login button.

```
...

<div className="auth-form-inputLine auth-form-submitBtn-container" id="auth-login-submitBtnContainer">
   <button onClick={this.handleFormSubmit} className="auth-form-submitBtn">
      {this.state.submitting ? <ButtonLoader /> : <h2 className="text">Login</h2>}
   </button>
</div>

...
```

---

[ButtonLoader.js] There are moving three dots.

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles/ButtonLoader.css";

const ButtonLoader = () => {
  return (
    <div class="spinner">
        <div class="bounce1"></div>
        <div class="bounce2"></div>
        <div class="bounce3"></div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ButtonLoader;
```

[ButtonLoader.css]

```
.spinner {
    margin: 100px auto 0;
    width: 70px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  .spinner > div {
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    background-color: #333;
  
    border-radius: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-animation: sk-bouncedelay 1.4s infinite ease-in-out both;
    animation: sk-bouncedelay 1.4s infinite ease-in-out both;
  }
  
  .spinner .bounce1 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: -0.32s;
    animation-delay: -0.32s;
  }
  
  .spinner .bounce2 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: -0.16s;
    animation-delay: -0.16s;
  }
  
  @-webkit-keyframes sk-bouncedelay {
    0%, 80%, 100% { -webkit-transform: scale(0) }
    40% { -webkit-transform: scale(1.0) }
  }
  
  @keyframes sk-bouncedelay {
    0%, 80%, 100% { 
      -webkit-transform: scale(0);
      transform: scale(0);
    } 40% { 
      -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
      transform: scale(1.0);
    }
  }
```

Comment: there is a `Spinner` component in` bootstrap`. here is the link https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/spinners/

Comment: try to remove `margin` from `.spinner` in your css. I think it is  `css` issues causing your problem.

Comment: @Jerry Thank you! Removing the margin fixed the problem.